# what is SQL Server Money equivalent datatype in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

we are working on Delphi 7 and SQL server 2008. 
SQl server Money Field size is //-922,337,203,685,477.5808 to 922,337,203,685,477.5807

what is equivalent in Delphi? we need to add some validations on Delphi side not to allow size more than sql server money field.

Comment: That would presumably be `Currency`, although I'm not sure about its size. However, I'd be suspicious if you need to handle values of such a great size at all in the first place.

Comment: we need to add some check not to exceed the limit. so i thought lets add money limitation :) since back end field is money. i will check with currency.

Comment: @Jerry Actually, size is not the only reason to consider `Currency`. Because its internal representation is an integer with 4 implicit decimal places, it can represent any (in range) number with up to 4 decimals precisely. `Double` (and similarly `Extended`) cannot do the same; in spite of their ability to support much larger ranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Currency`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Real_Types) is the equivalent type.

- It's stored as a 64-bit integer with implied 4 decimal places.
- It's main advantage over `Double` is the fact that it provides precise representation of decimal numbers with up to 4 digits. E.g. `0.1` cannot be precisely represented as a `Double` value. Whereas with `Currency`, all numbers in the range `-922337203685477.5807 .. 922337203685477.5807` can be precisely represented.
- Note that it has a disadvantage compared to `Double` in that it supports a range of values comparatively 'close' to zero. `Double` supports a much larger range by discarding precision beyond 15-16 digits: `2.23e-308 .. 1.79e+308`

Comment: Lower end of range is  -922337203685477.5808

Comment: @DavidDubois Thanks. Quite right that would be the theoretical minimum. Given that I copied the range from the link: I don't know if there's an error in the documentation or if Delphi reserves the value as a sentinel. I'll do some testing before updating.